# Regex pattern for string not bounded by character

Tags: java, regex

I need java pattern for string not bounded by a character.

I have a string (as mentioned below), with some curly brackets bounded by single quotes and other curly brackets that are not. I want to replace the curly brackets that are not bounded by single quotes, with another string.
Original string:

```
this is single-quoted curly '{'something'}' and this is {not} end
```

Needs to be converted to

```
this is single-quoted curly '{'something'}' and this is <<not>> end
```

Notice that the curly brackets { } that are not bounded by single quotes have been replaced with << >>.

However, my code prints (character gets eaten up) the text as

```
this is single-quoted curly '{'something'}' and this is<<no>> end
```

when I use the pattern

```
[^']([{}])
```

My code is

```
String regex = "[^']([{}])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if ( "{".equals(matcher.group(1)) ) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(strBuffer, "&lt;&lt;");
    } else if ( "}".equals(matcher.group(1))) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(strBuffer, "&gt;&gt;");
    }
}
matcher.appendTail(strBuffer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a clear use case for zero-width assertions. The regex you need isn't very complex:

```
String 
   input = "this is single-quoted curly '{'something'}' and this is {not} end",
  output = "this is single-quoted curly '{'something'}' and this is <<not>> end";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?<!')\\{(.*?)\\}(?!')", "<<$1>>")
                        .equals(output));
```

prints

```
true
```

Comment: +1, Thank you for pointing out the flaw in my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: Sorry everybody, unable to Vote Up on answers (says... not enough reputations). Have answered Yes to the "Was this post useful to you?" question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the negative lookahead / lookbehind constructs from [the special constructs section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) of the Java [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation.

Comment: One "simpler" way is to use capturing group and backreference in replacement string.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, but I wouldn't call that simpler, I'd call it messier. I like to put all pattern matching into the pattern if it's possible, and not into the processing logic.

Comment: It's "simpler" (in quote), since it may not apply to everyone. Of course, personally, I'd use look-around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String regex = "([^'])([{}])";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        if ("{".equals(matcher.group(2))) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(strBuffer, matcher.group(1) + "<<");
        } else if ("}".equals(matcher.group(2))) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(strBuffer,matcher.group(1) + ">>");
        }
    }
    matcher.appendTail(strBuffer);
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I tried a few regex-s unsuccessfully but this is great. :)